# apt-get install/remove/reinstall doesn't work. Python errors

Tags: command-line, apt, package-management, software-center, dpkg

Recently I tried to install the ubuntu desktop on my ubuntu server 14. The installation failed hard.

I tried several things fixing it and did a lot of research. But I couldn't find anything helpful.

This is the output when i try to reinstall ubuntu-desktop.

http://pastebin.com/60TM3ePn

Comment: To whoever downvoted this, can you explain why?  It seems like a reasonable question to me.

Comment: Please put only relevant information in your question or else no one will be able to answer. If you do not know what is relevant and what is not, better put the information somewhere else and share the link to that file in your question

Comment: I tried to install the ubuntu-drivers-common module manually.

I Downloaded the .deb file of the module and started the package installer with it. It did not work. After that I tried extracting the .deb File and ran the .sh scripts for installing. Got the same errors.

Comment: you should not be downloading deb files. packages are available through apt-get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it myself. I set up a Ubuntu server VM (The exact same Ubuntu server version and so on). Then I copied `/usr/lib/python3.4/*` from the vanilla ubuntu server via ftp on my other server with the problems. On this system i moved `/usr/lib/python3.4/*` in a temp folder. After that i put in the vanilla python3.4 folder in the `/usr/lib/python3.4` folder. Then I copied the old python3.4 (the one in the temp folder) over the `/usr/lib/python3.4` folder.

So I simply replaced the old python3.4 with the new. And then copied the old over the new.

After all that I ran `apt-get -f install`.
I got a lot of errors. They all told me that my python3.4 was not configured jet.

So I ran `apt-get --reinstall install python3`.
It worked fine.

At the end I ran "apt-get -f install" again and it installed every Broken package fine and everything was beautiful correct. :D

I know it is not a really smart way to solve it though.
And sure not something I would recommend. But well, if you are desperate enough...

Answer (score 1):

run the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-drivers-common/$(lsb_release -c -s) python3-update-manager/$(lsb_release -c -s) update-manager/$(lsb_release -c -s)
```

if that doesn't work, try this:

```
sudo dpkg -P ubuntu-drivers-common 
sudo dpkg -P python3-update-manager 
sudo dpkg -P update-manager
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-drivers-common update-manager python3-update-manager
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop/$(lsb_release -c -s)
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/apt-get.html

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto

http://www.tecmint.com/useful-basic-commands-of-apt-get-and-apt-cache-for-package-management/

Comment: Thanks. But it did not solve the problem. ` dpkg -P ubuntu-drivers-common
dpkg: error processing package ubuntu-drivers-common (--purge):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting a removal
Errors were encountered while processing:
 ubuntu-drivers-common
` got the same error with the update-manager.

Comment: The python3-update-manager has dependency problems. "apt-get clean" and "apt-get update" also fails. I get the same python errors as always. Also the Reinstallation of the two modules fail the same way with the same errors. They all drop the python errors in [link]http://pastebin.com/60TM3ePn .

Comment: This is the Output of  apt-get dist-upgrade http://pastebin.com/MhehFRMF

Comment: @NumericError then run `sudo apt-get -f install`

Comment: @NumericError the problem is that you are trying to install packages from the wrong distro and so they are not available throught the package manager for your distro. Did you run the first three commands? if so, and if they installed, you should NOT try to purge the packages you just installed. Go ahead and run the first three commands again DO NOT run the `dpkg -P` commands and please report any errors.

Comment: @NumericError please provide a list of packages you downloaded and tried to install and/or please provide any changes to your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file or files found in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`

Comment: @NumericError also, you didn't include the full code!!!! missing `/$(lsb_release -c -s)` no wonder you are getting errors.